# Scheduling Cucumber test features to run repeatedly

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rubymine-7

I have a Cucumber test (feature files) in the RubyMine IDE and lately I have a need to execute one of the feature repeatedly on a scheduled time.

I haven't found a way to do so. Any idea or thoughts on scheduling that feature file?

Comment: Use tag annotations. Then, create a new job that will run only these tests that are marked only with these tags. 
Example:

- Job CI(nightly) -  run all available test
- Job Repeatedly - run all tests with tag @repeatedly 

Documentation: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=java#tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply installing Jenkins on my machine from its official site,https://jenkins-ci.org/. I configured master and slave nodes on my own machine because I just needed to run one feature file(it has the script I want to run on daily basis).

Although, it is recommended to configure slave on a different machine if we have multiple jobs to run and our jobs are resource intensive.

There is a very good illustration on installing, configuring and running jobs in this link http://yakiloo.com/setup-jenkins-and-windows/

Answer (score 2):

You can create a cron job which will execute a rake.

> The software utility Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like
>   computer operating systems. People who set up and maintain software
>   environments use cron to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to
>   run periodically at fixed times, dates, or intervals.

These links might help

[How to create a cron job using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878600/how-to-create-cronjob-using-bash)

[how to create a cron job to run a ruby script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066489/how-to-create-a-cron-job-to-run-a-ruby-script)

http://rake.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Thanks mrtyormaa. It would be more helpful to know if somebody has scheduled their cucumber feature file to run on a daily basis. I am not quite sure how to put .feature file in the cron job.